# How to process image once selected?

Tags: java, android, file-io, filesystems

I'm retriving image from a IO file manager (one's installed). Anyhow when I try to retrieve an image I'm not sure where it's gone? Or how to save it as a bitmap?

Code below:

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    if(v.getId() == R.id.facebook_icon || v.getId() == R.id.facebook_text)
    {
        //Facebook
    }

    if(v.getId() == R.id.camera_icon || v.getId() == R.id.camera_text)
    {
        //Camera
    }

    if(v.getId() == R.id.folder_icon || v.getId() == R.id.folder_text)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    }
}

protected void onActivityForResult()
{
    //Where is the image? How to get?
    System.out.println("Image gotton");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are not overriding onActivityResult. Note the method signature: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int, int, android.content.Intent)

You should be using @Override annotations so you know when something's wrong.

Try something like:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
    }
}
```

Comment: How does @Override tell you what's wrong? Doesn't the system log already do this?

Thanks for the answer I've almost got it working :-)

Comment: @OllyDixon using the Override annotation lets you take advantage of the compiler checking to make sure you actually are overriding a method when you think you are. If you put that annotation and then write a method in such a way that it doesn't override anything, you'll see an error.